# Using facet_wrap with r ggmaps while keeping entire world geography in each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to show the world as 5 different quintiles of economic complexity

```
country_complexity_2021 <- read_csv("/Documents/Youtube Videos/economicsofimperialism/Data/complexity rankings/country-complexity-2021.csv") %>%
  gather(key = "year", value = "economic_complexity", `ECI Rank 1995`:`COI Rank 2021`) %>%
  mutate(
    type = str_sub(year, start=1, end=-6),
    year = str_sub(year, start=-4),
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Country = recode(Country,
                     "United States of America" = "USA",
                     "Turkiye" = "Turkey",
                     "Czechia" =  "Czech Republic")
  ) %>%
  filter(type == "ECI", year == 2021) %>%
  mutate(quintiles = cut(economic_complexity, breaks = c(-Inf, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, Inf))) 
  

world_map_2 <- map_data("world") %>%
  filter(lat > -57) %>%
  left_join(country_complexity_2021, join_by("region" == "Country"))

ggplot(world_map_2, aes(long, lat, fill = economic_complexity, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(colour="gray", linewidth=0.2) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(~quintiles) +
  labs(title = "Economic Complexity by Country", 
       caption = "Source: Harvard Atlas of Economic Complexity 2021") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y= element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    legend.position="bottom",
    plot.title = element_text(size = 10, family=my_font),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 8, family=my_font),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text( size=3, family=my_font),
    strip.text = element_text(size=8, family=my_font),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.2, "cm"),
    plot.caption = element_text(size = 7, color="dark gray", family=my_font)
  ) + scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Reds")
```

produces this image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGi7I.png)

But I would prefer it to show the whole world map, but with countries not in the given quintile shaded in gray. Not sure exactly how to go about this though.

I was expecting the image to show the gray by default, but in hindsight that was obviously wrong

Comment: You could use a second `geom_polygon` to add a base layer with the world map. Make sure that the data used for the base layer does not contain the variable you facet by.